# Причина повторения кода после вызова процедуры через call

Tags: ассемблер

Только начал изучать ассемблер и мне не совсем понятно, как работает вызов функции. Есть процедура clearScreen, которая очищает консоль. В коде я ее вызываю через call. Но тогда код

```
PRINT "x = " 
call scan_num
```

начинает исполнятся бесконечно. То есть, когда я после ввода значения х нажимаю Enter, программа очищает консоль и снова запрашивает значение. Строка END не выводится. Почему так происходит? Помогите решить проблему. Заранее благодарю.

```
org 100h
include 'emu8086.Inc'   

.data
    table dw 0, 1, 2  
    a db ?
    x db ?
.code
    PRINT "a = "
    call scan_num
    mov a, cl 
    clearScreen proc   
        push ax  ; зберігаємо результат обчислень у стек
        mov ax, 03 ; 2 наступні команди очищають консоль
        int 10h 
        pop ax ; поновлюємо результат обчислення у регістр 
    clearScreen endp
    PRINT "x = " 
    call scan_num  
    call clearScreen
    PRINT "END"
hlt
define_scan_num
define_print_num
define_print_num_uns
END
```

Comment: Инструкции лежат в коде именно в том порядке как вы написали. раз вы написали процедуру в середине кода, она там и лежит и когда она оканчивается управление попадает на следующую за ней инструкцию, т.е. на print. call этот то же jmp, только он еще кладет в стек адрес возврата, воспользоваться им и вернуться к точке вызова можно с помощью ret. И что бы это корректно работало функция должна быть не в середине кода, а отдельно. Кроме того не стоит использовать hlt, она останавливает работу процессора и машина зависает.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался